# Mobile Automation Testing Problem in OPPO Mobile in Appium

Tags: java, android, automation, appium-android

Here is the Code is there any method to run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, AWTException {

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "OPPO A31");
    cap.setCapability("udid", "EQEMCQ4PHISGJFOB");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
    cap.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
    cap.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);

    URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/home_button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/search_box_text")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement srcbar = driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar"));
srcbar.sendKeys("Flipkart ");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        "//android.view.View[@content-desc=\"Flipkart https://www.flipkart.com Flipkart\"]/android.view.View[2]"))
        .click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.TextView"))
        .click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
WebElement flpsrc = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.EditText"));
flpsrc.sendKeys("IPhone");
Thread.sleep(3000);
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
}
```

The DesiredCapabilities are given correctly but the code is not working.

Comment: can you attach some screenshots of the error this code generates?

Comment: Here is the screenshort take a look https://imgur.com/9K4cYgN

Answer (score 1):

Try these capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.0");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "OPPO A31");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UIAutomator2");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome")
```

Comment: This Capabilities also showing same error

Answer (score 0):

The Capabilities cap.setCapability("noReset", true); it should be as noreset
the only the it will skip that and move to automation

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, AWTException {

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "OPPO A31");
cap.setCapability("udid", "EQEMCQ4PHISGJFOB");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
cap.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
cap.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);

URL url = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);

driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/home_button")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/search_box_text")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement srcbar = driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/url_bar"));
srcbar.sendKeys("Flipkart ");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        "//android.view.View[@content-desc=\"Flipkart https://www.flipkart.com Flipkart\"]/android.view.View[2]"))
        .click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.widget.TextView"))
        .click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
WebElement flpsrc = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.EditText"));
flpsrc.sendKeys("IPhone");
Thread.sleep(3000);
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

}